# using combo box to populate another combo box so that a user can run a query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to let a user query a database by using combo boxes.  The first combo box shows a list of tables in the database.  When the user selects a table another query is ran which should populate the second combo box with the column names within that table (this will be used as a select for a query) I have the first combo box working but i am unable to get the second one to populate. Can anyone help with this? Many Thanks

here is my html code

```
<form id="ownQueryForm" name="ownQueryForm" method="POST" action="">

    <div id = "tableSelect_div">
        <P> Select table to Query: </P>

            <select name = "Tables" id = "Tables" onchange = 'this.form.submit()'>
                <option value = "blank"> Please choose a Table</option>
                <?php foreach (($tableContent) as $row) : ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $row['Tables_in_DB_EXECUTION_MANAGER_TEST']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Tables_in_DB_EXECUTION_MANAGER_TEST'];?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>

            </select>   


    </div>

    <div id = "columnSelect_div">
        <p>SELECT</p>
            <select name = "Columns" id = "Columns">
                <?php foreach (($columnContent) as $row) : ?>
                <option value = "<?php echo $row['COLUMN_NAME']; ?>"><?php echo $row['COLUMN_NAME'];?></option>
                <?php endforeach ?>
            </select>
    </div>


</form>
```

and here is my two queries so far

```
    public static function getTables(){
    global $db;

    $st = $db->prepare("show tables");
    $st ->execute();
    $table = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $table;


}

public static function getColumns(){
    global $db;
    $st = $db->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = :value ");
    $st->bindParam(':value', $_POST['Tables'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $st -> execute();
    $column = $st -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $column;
    //print_r($column);
}

}
```

I am using a controller that is used to render the getTable (which is in a model) and also to getColumns as two seperate functions on the same controller. can this be done?
I have this in the controller but it never gets run (unless i take out the if statement) and then it runs when the page loads

```
if (isset ( $_POST ['Tables'] )) {


$c = new ownQueryController();
$c ->queryRequest();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
'DESCRIBE ' . $_POST[ 'Tables' ]
```

Rather than

```
"SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = :value "
```

This should return a array of columns with their name, type, limit etc. You can then loop though each column and display it.

WARNING

You will need to make sure your POST data is safe to put into the query. As @andy suggested your table could potentially be dropped if you just use this.

Comment: If I posted `{'Tables' => "*tablename*; DROP TABLE *tablename*"}` then it would just drop that particular table.

Comment: Thats why I said you could use, it would give the required results. As with all POST data you will need to take security precautions. I dont think this deserved a down vote.

Comment: You should probably update the post to include that warning. It's amazing the amount of people that cut and paste unsecure code off this site :) I downvoted because of that but I will remove it.

Comment: `You last voted on this answer 1 hour ago Your vote is now locked in 
unless this answer is edited`

Comment: Ok thats a fair point, where possible I try and write barebones code to "push" people in the right direction to a solution. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: Awesome, all changed :)